# How to extract lines from a file when the second columns of a file matches the values in another file

Tags: linux, command-line, command

I got two files.

file 1:

```
4
14
18
45
53
60
64
102
106
158
162
```

file2:

```
28 1 2
54 1 2
90 1 1
103 1 1
155 1 17
191 1 1
235 1 1
245 4 1
275 4 1
362 4 1
377 18 1
391 18 1
413 18 2
466 18 2
492 18 2
494 18 41
498 45 1
522 45 1
529 57 3
542 53 1
560 58 6
562 164 25
568 164 5
```

I want to extract the value from file2 if the second column of file two matches the value in file 1.

So the expected output will be:

```
    245 4 1
    275 4 1
    362 4 1
    377 18 1
    391 18 1
    413 18 2
    466 18 2
    492 18 2
    494 18 41
    498 45 1
    522 45 1
    542 53 1
```

I saw many of the solution online is using python or Perl, however, I want to use linux command to do this, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it?

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]++};FNR!=NR{if($2 in a){print}}' file1 file2
245 4 1
275 4 1
362 4 1
377 18 1
391 18 1
413 18 2
466 18 2
492 18 2
494 18 41
498 45 1
522 45 1
542 53 1
```

Explanation:

- we hand awk both files (order is important in this case!).
- as long as we read the first file (`FNR==NR`) we store each value in an array `a[$1]++`
- when we reach the second file we just check if values from the second file's second column (`$2`) are in the array; if yes, we print them.